# Error arising during implementing BERT on classifying text problem

Tags: matlab, text-classification, bert-language-model, data-partitioning

Recently Matlab has launched BERT in their git repository. There's an example of classifying text data using BERT. I am trying to run this code as it is.

Here, I am struck at a point where data fails to partitioned into test data.

The code block I am trying is following:

```
%% 
mdl = bert;
%% 
tokenizer = mdl.Tokenizer
%% 
filename = "factoryReports.csv";
data = readtable(filename,"TextType","string");
head(data)
%% 
data.Category = categorical(data.Category);
classes = categories(data.Category);
numClasses = numel(classes)
%% 
data.Tokens = encode(tokenizer, data.Description);
%% 
cvp = cvpartition(data.Category,"Holdout",0.2);
dataTrain = data(training(cvp),:);
dataValidation = data(test(cvp),:);
```

The error is showing on the last line of the execution and the error is following:

```
Unable to use a value of type cvpartition as an index.
Error in Untitled (line 18)
dataValidation = data(test(cvp),:);
```

What might be the reason of this and how to resolve this issue? I am looking for your advice.

Comment: Where are the training and test variables defined ? You need to check.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing Matlab and opening it again. It worked for me.